# Have > as a variable so it can be < or > in Case is

Tags: string, formula

For example; currVal > ResetVal. I would like the > to be a variable so I can call it as <, =, <> etc... rather than having to repeat the process since at times it could be currVal < ResetVal, currVal = ResetVal, etc...   I tried dirVal = " > " as follows but it didn't work. Thanks.

Sub dirVal()

```
Dim currVal, resetVal As Integer
Dim dirVal As String

currVal = 1
resetVal = 2
dirVal = ">"

Debug.Print currVal & dirVal & resetVal
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

In most programming languages, variables typically have a data type, like string, integer, array, etc. What you want to put into a variable is an operator. That is not a data type for a variable.

Depending on the programming language you're working with, which you haven't specified in your question, you can put together the whole expression as a string and then evaluate the string.

In VBA you would be able to use the Evaluate() function for that.

```
Debug.Print Evaluate(currVal & dirVal & resetVal)
```

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.